# Manipulating Dates in PHP without using Regular Expressions

Tags: php, time

Is there a way to change a date from

```
1985-12-15
```

to

```
1985-12
```

without using a regular Expression?

Comment: Props for trying to avoid an unnecessary regexp. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php echo date('Y-m', strtotime('1985-12-15')); ?>
```

That should do it.

This will, using strtotime, convert 1985-12-15 to a unix timestamp. The date function then takes a second parameter timestamp on which to format the date.

Answer (score 4):

Convert the date to time via [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) then use [`date`](http://php.net/date) to output in correct date format, like so:

```
<?php    
echo date('Y-m', strtotime('1985-12-15'));
```

Comment: Bugger, beaten to it by 6 seconds

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm just stupid, but if you only want the beginning of that date, stored as a string, can't you just use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to extract the 7 characters at the beginning of that string ?

A bit like this, for instance :

```
$input = '1985-12-15';

$output = substr($input, 0, 7);
var_dump($output);
```

Which does give you :

```
string '1985-12' (length=7)
```

No need for any date-manipulation related function, in this case -- and this will probably be even faster/cheapier that parsing the string to a date and all that.

*(Yeah, I know, premature optimisation ^^ )*

Comment: @noob52 : well noted -- the question, in this case, is "will that date be stored as 1985-01-01, or as 1985-1-1 ?" ; I would use the first solution, and I admit I didn't think about the second one ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
$myDate = date('Y-m',strtotime('1985-12-15'));
echo $myDate // prints '1985-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

not best to `substr($date,0,strrpos($date,'-'));`?

that would be cheapest?

Answer (score 0):

If you think a regular expression isn't "cheap", then time functions will almost certainly be even more expensive: you would need to convert the string into a time value, then format it back into a string...

Answer (score 0):

do you have that time value already in a array or do you whant such a like output come from the date function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure how the date will be formated, you should use the strtotime function, otherwise its probably as easy to do if the format is yyyy-mmm-dd or yy-m-d.

```
$datearray = explode('-',$date);
echo $datearray[0].'-'.$datearray[1];
```